# I've got a bunch of url aliases can I just say *.example.com in my crossdomain.xml file and have it work?

Tags: cross-domain

Here's my current crossdomain.xml:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="www.example.com" />
   <allow-access-from domain="example.com" />
   <allow-access-from domain="example-alias.com.com" />
   <allow-access-from domain="www.example-alias..com" />
   <allow-access-from domain="otherexample.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I'm going to be adding a few other aliases and subdomians, etc. Can I simplify this to:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*example.com" />
   <allow-access-from domain="*example-alias.com.com" />
   <allow-access-from domain="*otherexample.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slightly different (you're missing the dot). See the [cross-domain policy file specification from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html#domain-matching).

Comment: Yeah, it's a little bit counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Close.

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.example.com" />
    <allow-access-from domain="*.mail.other-example.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```